# Add data to a boost property_tree

Tags: c++, xml, boost-variant, boost-propertytree

I have a simple tree structure stored in XML and use `boost::property_tree::ptree` to read and extract the information. I then recreate the tree using `std::maps` so that I can store data in the leaves. This works well and I like the separation of the fixed tree structure from the data but I feel that I am duplicating a lot of code and that if I could add a class to each leaf node in the ptree I could greatly simplify my code.

As a possible slight complication I am using `boost::variant` in the class I wish to store in the leaves.

My main question is should I try to add dynamic data to the ptree and secondly, if so, do you have any suggestions of the best way to add it.

Comment: Hi Ant, I love the fact that you got the Tumbleweed badge for this question! Oh wait, has the badge just been taken away since this comment went live?!? P.S. I don't know the answer...

Comment: The Tumbleweed badge is still there and the question remains unanswered. :-(

Comment: You could trying posting a bounty, might get more interest. Oh also you haven't got c++ as one of the tags.